# How to get the id of a dragged element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag

I want to get the `id` of a dragged element in **JavaScript** in the drop event handler.

The green `div` with the `id` of `place5` is draggable and the drop location is another `div` with the `id` of `dropArea` (with a red border).

How do I get the `id` of the `place5` `div` in the drop event handler?

```js
function dragEventHandler(theEvent) {
  theEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", theEvent.target.id);
  // some code here.
}

function dropEventHandler(theEvent) {
  // how to get the id of div with id "place5" here?
}
```

```css
.mainArea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

#place5 {
  background: green;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropArea" class="mainArea" ondrop="dropEventHandler(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
</div>
<div id="place5" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragEventHandler(event);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Perform the reverse of what you did during the drag start event.

So on dragstart you have:

```
function dragEventHandler(theEvent) {
    theEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", theEvent.target.id);
    //Some code here.
}
```

Thus on drop you would have:

```
function dropEventHandler(theEvent) {
    var id = theEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    //Other code here.
}
```