# How to write data into array Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Data is written to the array, but not correctly.I need to write to the array.

for example like this

```
 {"arr_block1":["COOL","Random_text"],"arr_block2":["GREAT"],"arr_block3": 
 ["beautiful"]}
```

'Random_text' is what is written in text_write

Random text inserts a void

```
  {"arr_block1":["COOL"," "],"arr_block2":["GREAT"],"arr_block3": 
  ["beautiful"]}
```

This is a static text that is in the block.

```
   ($(this).text())
```

This is the text that the user enters in textarea

```
  elements.push(text_write);
```

P.S. I drag items from drag to drop.

arr_block1  arr_block2 arr_block3

it's three drops
it is necessary, for example, that a guest drag a text reader into a certain drop, for example, mass_block3, and that he enrolls there, otherwise, no matter how I try, it is recorded for everyone too

```
{"arr_block1":["COOL","Random_text"],"arr_block2":["GREAT","Random_text"],"arr_block3":["beautiful","Random_text"]}
```

it is not necessary, he should write only to the drop where he was put

```
$(this).find('.wrap').each(function() {
    var text_write = document.getElementById("my_textarea").value;
    if (!(text_write).empty) {
        elements.push(text_write);
    } else if ((($(this).text()).empty) && ((textt).empty)) {
        elements.push(" ");
    } else if (!(($(this).text()).empty))
        elements.push(($(this).text()));
});
```

it's three drops
it is necessary, for example, that a guest drag a text reader into a certain drop, for example, mass_block3, and that he enrolls there, otherwise, no matter how I try, it is recorded for everyone too

```
{"arr_block1": ["COOL", "Random_text"], "arr_block2": ["GREAT", "Random_text"], "arr_block3": ["beautiful", "Random_text"]}
```

it is not necessary, he should write only to the drop where he was put

It inserts all the elements in the array with the value from textrea, but I need to get to a specific one, to which I drag as

```
   ($(this).text())
```

Comment: Provide a sandbox demo...question is a bit confusing without seeing what is going on. Also not sure how you come up with `empty` property for a string unless you added to String prototype

Comment: Now there is no opportunity to show. There are Two Dragena with static text in the block and one textarea where the user enters the text. When I drag two dragons to the first ```arr_block1``` and second ```arr_block2``` drop with static text, then with the help of (This text) I take the value and save it to the desired array. But the textrea, dragging to the third drop, is saved not only in ```arr_block3```, but also in ```arr_block2``` and ```arr_block1```

Comment: this is related to ```elements.push``` like that

Comment: Hard to help without a runnable [mcve]

Comment: `if (!(text_write).empty) {`, the `.value` of a textarea is a `string`.  `.empty` is not a property of `string`.  Try `if ( text_write ) {...`.

Comment: Yes, I tried, still saves the result of the textarea to all, but I need to a certain

Comment: it is necessary as something else to get the value from textarea, otherwise I get the value from a static using ```this text``` and he understands that I take the value from the dragen I am dragging, and I take the meaning of the text differently, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

---

The original question was confusing, but the screen shot helped.  See if this gets the result you are looking for.

```html
<script>
    function getData () {
        // initialize the result
        var result = {},
            $cards = $(".hexagon-cards-drop"),
            myTextArea = document.getElementById ( "my_textarea" ),
            $temp = $("#temp");

        $cards.each ( function () {
            result [ this.dataset.type ] = [];
        } ).on ( "drop", function () {
            result [ this.dataset.type ].push ( myTextArea.value );

            // if you want to see the value on the screen, you could try
            // something similar to this ( remove comments as needed )
            // $(this).append ( "<span class='wrap'>" + myTextArea.value + "</span>" );
        } );

        $temp.on ( "click", function () {
            var myJsonString = JSON.stringify ( result );
            console.log ( myJsonString );

            $.ajax ( {
                url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'save_data',
                    data: myJsonString
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                    $temp.text ( "Upload to the server 5 sec" );
                },
                success: function ( data ) {
                    $temp.text ( "Send" );
                    alert ( data );

                    // if you want to remove the spans after saving
                    //$cards.each ( function () {
                    //    $(this).remove ( ".wrap" );
                    //} );

                    // to clear the data
                    //for ( var name in result ) {
                    //    result[name].length = 1;
                    //}
                }
            } );
        }
    }

    getData ();
</script>
```

---

Not sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like there are a couple problems in your code.  One may be a typo here: `} else if ((($(this).text()).empty) && ((textt).empty)) {` where you have `textt` - that is unless `textt` is a variable name that was declared further up in the code and not included in the question.  Otherwise, the code is attempting comparisons on properties of strings `.empty` which are not actual properties of javascript strings, so for example, `var val = "".empty // -> undefined`.

Try this code and see if it helps:

```
$(this).find('.wrap').each(function() {
    var text_write = document.getElementById("my_textarea").value,
        text_val = $(this).text();

    if (text_write) {
        elements.push(text_write);
    } else if ( !text_val && !text ) {
        elements.push(" ");
    } else if ( text_val ) {
        elements.push( text_val );
    }
});
```

Comment: with this code it does like this
```{"arr_block1": ["COOL", "Text_from_textarea"], "arr_block2": ["GREAT", "Text_from_textarea"], "arr_block3": ["beautiful", "Text_from_textarea"]}```

but I need to, if I drag the text in the third drop, so that it is
```{"arr_block1": ["COOL"], "arr_block2": ["GREAT"], "arr_block3": ["beautiful", "Text_from_textarea"]}```

Comment: @Josef In that case, I would need to see the code from the drop event - including how the `elements` array is chosen - to understand how to help. :-)

Comment: @Josef Can you update the question with a more complete code example?

Comment: I came home, and I forgot the code on my computer at work, so I can’t throw (((

Comment: @Josef Well, feel free to reply later if you still need help. :-)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/og74ag
https://prnt.sc/og7fxt
https://prnt.sc/og78fx

I only have such screenshots

Comment: ttps://jsfiddle.net/3mja3mm1/ this is not mine, but drag drops work for me according to this principle. Only I have a static text in blocks and another textarea

Comment: thank you very much. Tomorrow I'll go to work a couple of hours earlier and try. I hope that will help a lot. I can still write to you, if something does not go?only I don’t know if it will work or not, since it finds me in ```.wrap``` in the drop when I’ve dragged it and then starts the action

Comment: @Josef Sure!  I may have overlooked something.  Let me know and I will reply as soon as I check my messages.

Comment: I looked at your code carefully and you are sure that the static text that is in some drag will also be recorded?

Comment: just a static text is in a ````.wrap````. And when I drag the wrap to the drop, he finds it and write the text down there.

Comment: @Josef You are correct.  I did not consider the item that was dragged, because in the example code the text was used from the textarea.  You may need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950304/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-dragged-element-in-javascript#25616091)

Comment: function below in html, it takes the text that is already transferred. Static it outputs to the console (I don’t know why the output doesn’t work through the sandbox, but it exists), but now you need to please insert your code and make it work for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/nilsons20000/8nsdovpy/18/

Comment: please((((((((( help me

Comment: @Josef Sorry to say, but I can not simply "make it work" for you.  That is not the purpose here.  I understand you have a problem that needs to be solved.  However, starting with a wall of code, which is broken in many places, is not productive.  You will need to start cleanly and work through each piece until you understand it, then put all the pieces back together.  When you get to that point, and you need help with something more specific than "make this work", then I will be better able to help.  Please understand, everyone must go through these kinds of troubles in order to learn. :-)

Comment: It works on my server, I do not know why it does not work in the console in the sandbox. It saves these static data into an array.

Comment: @Josef Then you must look at each part.  For that I just use a single line of code to write to the console so I know what is happening and where.  Then I copy and paste and later delete that line of code, and run the program many times and change or move that line of code until I understand what is happening.  Take some time and try this.  Do not forget to remove that line of code when you no longer need it.  Practice this process and it will help you work through problems like this.  When you understand better what is happening, then you will know what more to ask.

Comment: it is as if the click function itself does not see in the sandbox

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nilsons20000/8nsdovpy/64/
Everything worked in the sandbox. Please fill in the text and drag two dragons to the drop. and see the console.If it does not work, then in the FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS section, change to jqure 3.3.1

Comment: The fiddle does not work because it does not have all the code from the sandbox.  You can see this if you run the fiddle, follow your instructions for text and drop, and read the errors on the console.

Comment: those errory that shows in the console do not affect everything ... drag? drag and drop. I care how to write to the array correctly.